# State Recording DataTemplate Windows Store

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Windows Store application and I have a ListBox with a custom DataTemplate. I've realized that (in my attempts) I can't modify Styles when doing State Recording in the XAML and I can't modify my DataTemplate for the snapped state without modifying the other states. How do I work around this specifically for Styles or for DataTemplates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that the windows template projects deal with this is to have multiple instances of the data template, and make them visible or hidden based in the state.